# Python: Same variable using in a elif stage but last part throws XXX not defined error

Tags: python, python-3.x

rest part works good but
if the last line triggered, it throws `NameError: name 'rastolfostr' is not defined` error, `rastolfostr` is already set before the if elif statements, however here's the code

```
    @client.event
async def on_message(message):
    lowcasemsg=message.content.lower()
    if lowcasemsg.startswith('.astolfo'):
       rasfolto=random.randint(1, 100000000)
       rasfoltostr=str(rasfolto)
       if lowcasemsg.startswith('.astolfo nsfw'):
         astolfolink=apibase + 'from=astolfo&nsfw=1&img=' + rasfoltostr
       elif lowcasemsg.startswith('.astolfo sfw'):
         astolfolink=apibase + 'from=astolfo&nsfw=0&img=' + rasfoltostr
       elif lowcasemsg.startswith('.astolfo mix'):
         astolfolink=apibase + 'from=astolfo&nsfw=2&img=' + rasfoltostr
       else:
         astolfolink=apibase + 'from=astolfo&nsfw=0&img=' + rastolfostr
    await message.reply (astolfolink, mention_author=False)
```

i was planning to check for other 3 and if non of them, give the last one which is sfw.

if the last one triggered, this happens, rest are works
[image: Screenshot from terminal]

Comment: Please provide the expected see [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.
We expect a minimal working example of the problem, including appropriate code to trace the internal operation.
Your posted code does not run; it's the def of a function that isn't called.

Comment: Off-site links and images of text are not acceptable; your posting must be self-contained, in keeping with the purpose of this site.

We also expect that you will trace the suspect values just before the point of error.

Comment: Also, if `lowcasemsg.startswith('.astolfo'):` is not true, none of the subsequent variables get defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sigh, variable name that you've assigned -> rasfoltostr (which isn't rastolfostr). Pls pay attention to detail next time